# Triggered Send Errors - access subscribers for failed send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

We have a triggered send, which is throwing some errors. We want to extract those who didn't get the email - but the challenge is the data extension is emptied occassionally so we cannot simply do a "SourceDE" minus "_Sent" query.

How would we go about accessing the error list shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking at this data?

[NotSent Tracking Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313980&type=1)

Comment: I haven't - will try and revert back :)