# External FTP File Transfer Activity Error in Automation Studio - Can't Change

Tags: marketing-cloud, files, automation, ftp, sftp

I'm trying to gather the errored emails in a triggered send. My question is the same as this one: [Triggered Send Errors - access subscribers for failed send?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173486/triggered-send-errors-access-subscribers-for-failed-send/173523)

However, when I attempt pull the errors, I get the following error: "ERROR:  An undefined error occurred. Contact your account representative if the error persists."

This looks like the same issue as this one: [External FTP File Transfer Activity Error in Automation Studio](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/205831/external-ftp-file-transfer-activity-error-in-automation-studio)

However, in our file locations setup, our current SFTP location is setup as a "Enhanced FTP Site Import Directory", and doesn't give a field to update the URL. The only way to update a URL would be to create a new SFTP location and input the url "ftp://ftp1.exacttarget.com" (we're on stack 1). Unfortunately when I attempt to do this and add its credentials to our external SFTP application, it will deny me access, even though I've created login credentials.